# Websocket timeout in Django Channels / Daphne

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

Short question version: what am I doing wrong in my Daphne config, or my Consumer code, or my client code?

```
channels==1.1.8
daphne==1.3.0
Django==1.11.7
```

Details below:

---

I am trying to keep a persistent Websocket connection open using Django Channels and the Daphne interface server. I am launching Daphne with mostly default arguments: `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 my_app.asgi:channel_layer`.

I am seeing the connections closing after some idle time in the browser, shortly over 20 seconds. The `CloseEvent` sent with the disconnect has a `code` value of `1006` (Abnormal Closure), no `reason` set, and `wasClean` set to false. This *should* be the server closing the connection without sending an explicit close frame.

The Daphne CLI has `--ping-interval` and `--ping-timeout` flags with default values of 20 and 30 seconds, respectively. This is documented as "The number of seconds a WebSocket must be idle before a keepalive ping is sent," for the former, and "The number of seconds before a WebSocket is closed if no response to a keepalive ping," for the latter. I read this as Daphne will wait until a WebSocket has been idle for 20 seconds to send a ping, and will close the Websocket if no response is received 30 seconds later. What I am seeing instead is connections getting closed after being 20 seconds idle. (Across three attempts with defaults, closed after 20081ms, 20026ms, and 20032ms)

If I change the server to launch with `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 --ping-interval 10 --ping-timeout 60 my_app.asgi:channel_layer`, the connections still close, around 20 seconds idle time. (After three attempts with updated pings, closed after 19892ms, 20011ms, 19956ms)

Code below:

---

`consumer.py`:

```
import logging

from channels import Group
from channels.generic.websockets import JsonWebsocketConsumer

from my_app import utilities

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class DemoConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    """
    Consumer echos the incoming message to all connected Websockets,
    and attaches the username to the outgoing message.
    """
    channel_session = True
    http_user_and_session = True

    @classmethod
    def decode_json(cls, text):
        return utilities.JSONDecoder.loads(text)

    @classmethod
    def encode_json(cls, content):
        return utilities.JSONEncoder.dumps(content)

    def connection_groups(self, **kwargs):
        return ['demo']

    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        super(DemoConsumer, self).connect(message, **kwargs)
        logger.info('Connected to DemoConsumer')

    def disconnect(self, message, **kwargs):
        super(DemoConsumer, self).disconnect(message, **kwargs)
        logger.info('Disconnected from DemoConsumer')

    def receive(self, content, **kwargs):
        super(DemoConsumer, self).receive(content, **kwargs)
        content['user'] = self.message.user.username
        # echo back content to all groups
        for group in self.connection_groups():
            self.group_send(group, content)
```

`routing.py`:

```
from channels.routing import route

from . import consumers

channel_routing = [
    consumers.DemoConsumer.as_route(path=r'^/demo/'),
]
```

`demo.js`:

```
// Tracks the cursor and sends position via a Websocket
// Listens for updated cursor positions and moves an icon to that location
$(function () {
  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/demo/');
  var icon;
  var moveTimer = null;
  var position = {x: null, y: null};
  var openTime = null;
  var lastTime = null;
  function sendPosition() {
    if (socket.readyState === socket.OPEN) {
      console.log('Sending ' + position.x + ', ' + position.y);
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(position));
      lastTime = Date.now();
    } else {
      console.log('Socket is closed');
    }
    // sending at-most 20Hz
    setTimeout(function () { moveTimer = null; }, 50);
  };
  socket.onopen = function (e) {
    var box = $('#websocket_box');
    icon = $('<div class="pointer_icon"></div>').insertAfter(box);
    box.on('mousemove', function (me) {
      // some browsers will generate these events much closer together
      // rather than overwhelm the server, batch them up and send at a reasonable rate
      if (moveTimer === null) {
        moveTimer = setTimeout(sendPosition, 0);
      }
      position.x = me.offsetX;
      position.y = me.offsetY;
    });
    openTime = lastTime = Date.now();
  };
  socket.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log("!!! CLOSING !!! " + e.code + " " + e.reason + " --" + e.wasClean);
    console.log('Time since open: ' + (Date.now() - openTime) + 'ms');
    console.log('Time since last: ' + (Date.now() - lastTime) + 'ms');
    icon.remove();
  };
  socket.onmessage = function (e) {
    var msg, box_offset;
    console.log(e);
    msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
    box_offset = $('#websocket_box').offset();
    if (msg && Number.isFinite(msg.x) && Number.isFinite(msg.y)) {
      console.log((msg.x + box_offset.left) + ', ' + (msg.y + box_offset.top));
      icon.offset({
        left: msg.x + box_offset.left,
        top: msg.y + box_offset.top
      }).text(msg.user || '');
    }
  };
});
```

`asgi.py`:

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

`settings.py`:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer',
        'ROUTING': 'main.routing.channel_routing',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [
                'redis://redis:6379/2',
            ],
            'symmetric_encryption_keys': [
                SECRET_KEY,
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see your **asgi.py** and your **settings.py**

Comment: Included asgi.py; after poking around more, I think the problem is partially with an nginx proxy, which has proxy timeouts set to 20 seconds. It should still be ok with Daphne sending pings after 15 seconds, though, so I think something else is still wrong.

Comment: In your template I suggest you to use the class **channels.WebSocketBridge** instead of **WebSocket**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The underlying problem turned out to be the nginx proxy in front of the interface server. The proxy was set to `proxy_read_timeout 20s;`. If there were keepalive pings generated from the server, these were not getting counted toward the upstream read timeout. Increasing this timeout to a larger value allows the Websocket to stay open longer. I kept `proxy_connect_timeout` and `proxy_send_timeout` at `20s`.